# quit 1000 of QThread - pyqt5

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, exit, qthread

I have `python` gui app using `Qt`

I'm using `pyqt5`

the app should creating 1000 or more `Qthreads`, each thread will use `pycurl` to open external URL

I'm using this code to open the threads:

```
self.__threads = []
# workerClass thread
for i in range(1000):
    workerInstance =  workerClass()
    workerInstance.sig.connect(self.ui.log.append)
    thread = QThread()
    self.__threads.append((thread, workerInstance))
    workerInstance.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.started.connect(workerInstance.worker_func)
    thread.start()
```

WorkerClass will use a simple `pycurl` to visit an external URL and emit signal to add some info on the log, here is the code:

```
class workerClass(QObject):
    x = 1
    sig = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, linksInstance, timeOut):
        super().__init__()
        self.linksInstance = linksInstance
        self.timeOut = timeOut

    @pyqtSlot()
    def worker_func(self):
        while self.x:
            # run the pycurl code
            self.sig.emit('success!') ## emit success message
```

Now the problem is with stopping all this, I used the below code for stop button:

```
def stop_func(self):
    workerClass.x = 0
    if self.__threads:
        for thread, worker in self.__threads:
            thread.quit()
            thread.wait()
```

changing the `workerClass.x` to 0 will stop the `while self.x` in the class `workerClass` and quit and wait should close all threads

all this is working properly, BUT only in the low amount of threads, 10 or may be 100
but if I rung 1000 threads, it takes much time, I wait for 10 minutes but it didn't stopped (mean threads not terminated), however the `pycurl` time out is only 15 seconds

I also used: `self.thread.exit()` `self.thread.quit()` `self.thread.terminate()` but it gives no difference

if any one have any idea about this, this will be really great :)

Comment: Do you have any evidence that using 1000's of threads provides any benefits? If not, you really should do some testing before assuming that adding more threads will improve performance. I suspect you will find that, in python, using a relatively small pool of threads can be much more efficient. For example, see: [Optimal Number of Threads in Python](http://edmundmartin.com/optimal-number-of-threads-in-python/).

Comment: yes it makes a huge difference using `pycurl`, also this app is a general app, the user should choose how many threads he want to use.

Comment: I don't see why the user should care about such implementation details.

Comment: PS: have you considered using [pycurl multi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8311408/984421)?

Comment: these details gives the user the full control to choose the speed and/or other factors, so he have the option to choose the timeout and the threads amount, also thanks for your advice to try pycurl multi, I will test it as it also may gives some better performance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some tries, I removed the pycurl code and test to start 10k QThreads and stopped it, and this working perfect without any errors. so I define that the error is with the pycurl code.

as per the advice of ekhumoro in the question comments, I may try to use pycurl multi

but for now I added this line to the pycurl code:

```
c.setopt(c.TIMEOUT, self.timeOut)
```

I was using only this:

```
c.setopt (c.CONNECTTIMEOUT, self.timeOut)
```

so now with the both 2 parameters all is properly working, starting and stopping bulk qthreads